# Do Jinchurikis bleed when a tailed beast is extracted?

Tags: naruto

Kushina had blood come out of her mouth when Obito extracted Kurama out of her. Why did this not happen to Naruto?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the bleeding was caused by the extraction of the tailed beast but was caused by the intense pain and struggle from her giving birth to naruto. As far as I remember only both naruto and gaara were shown when a tailed beast was extracted from them and both didn't have any blood.